# What does this function does ? Magento 2 billing-address.js

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, onestepcheckout

Would like to know what does this fucntion does in billing-address.js 
`initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            quote.paymentMethod.subscribe(function () {
                checkoutDataResolver.resolveBillingAddress();
            }, this);
            shippingRatesValidator.initFields(this.get('name') + '.form-fields');
        },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code written in this function will execute first